# CSS input boxes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am developing UI for my ASP.NET application and I have a logon form in which I have a box and inside the box I have the fields like this. (xxxx are the input boxes)

```
Name:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Email:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have kept the name and email with input boxes in a div but it works fine on IE7 but when I see it in mozilla or IE8 it appears very far right, how do I come up with the perfect placement on every browser?

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite hard. You should try to use a CSS framework like YUI CSS Grid or Blueprint rather than manually place everything by hand. It can alleviate a lot of pain.

As for your specific instance, it would help if you posted the relevant CSS snippets on your question so that people can offer intelligent answers.